How could life possibly evolve to the extreme conditions of the day side of a tidally locked Earth?
I'm currently brainstorming on a post-apocalyptic Earth. I initially thought of a massive asteroid collision event that drastically slowed down Earth's rotation to be around 1 Earth day = 1 Earth year and basically simulating a tidally locked state, but with regards to the survivability of life, I may have to go back to the drawing board and be a little creative about it. Life would have to recover and for the remaining life to evolve and adapt to it. Now, biological understanding would indicate that it would be very difficult to achieve, if not completely impossible, but entertain for a while that life would somehow find its way and thrive even in the extreme conditions of the perpetual daytime side of the world, not just in the habitable twilight zone. How would life evolve under these conditions? What specific characteristics would they have to gain evolutionarily to adapt?
As per your kind suggestions, we can maybe start focusing on the base level autotrophs as a specific part of the ecosystem under the conditions of the perpetual daylight side of the Earth.
Although I understand that its feasibility in the evolutionary biology perspective is questionable, so creative ideas are highly appreciated as well.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please limit this to ask either about human adaptation or evolution and colonization by unintelligent (probably microbial) life. It's fine to ask two related questions, either serially or at the same time, but limiting to one question per Question is SE policy and makes it easier to answer.

I'm pretty sure the amount of energy required to slow the rotation any significant amount would also liquify the crust.

too many questions, most of which are pure speculation. voting to close. If anything survives the impact some life will evolve, but we can;t even say anything surives the impact.

Please read the tags description: you have put two mutually exclusive tags, science-based and science-fiction. Pick only one!

(a) You're asking for a LOT. We barely understand how humans evolved... and we actually have end results and intermediate evidence to guide us. So this question probably violates the Book Rule (see [help/dont-ask]). (b) Adaptation is easier than evolution. Why do you think you need to start over? Has any event in Earth's history destoyed all life and required the planet to start over? (c) As mentioned, creating a justification for all life is probably too much. But we could help you with some [tag:creature-design] if you focus on just one creature in just one location.

It's speculative, and we could probably work to give the general principles to work with of the sort of adaptations that would be necessary, but..... you're talking about a whole ecosystem, autotrophs on up to the top predators of what eats them, along with parasites and all. It is broad. Perhaps an edit to focus on the base of the ecosystem, the energy-collectors, the plants to start with. Then a separate thread to take in the animals. It could be broken down further still.... but I reckon that should be enough to satisfy those who wish to stick by the rules rather than let flow the ideas.

Thanks for your suggestions and guidance. I have changed the tag from science-based to science-fiction as I acknowledge that the specific conditions of the tidally locked earth would fall quite outside the realm of possibility for life, biologically speaking.

I've put a vote-to-reopen on this because it looks to me like the reason for the closure had already been resolved by the time of the final VTC.

I am not a biologist, but a wind-driven migratory cycle might be feasible for sci-fi. Essentially a hyper-exaggerated version of the day/night cycle for normal plants, using cyclic wind currents instead of the rotation of the planet.
The asexually reproducing organism is found on particles of dust, or perhaps it's as big as a dust particle itself. It turns water, CO2, and sunlight into fuel on the day side, until it runs out of water. Running out of water causes a chemical change that makes the microbe go dormant until wind blows it to the cold side and it finds some water. The presence of water activates it and it spends the fuel it made on the day side, reacting some of it with oxygen for energy to gather more water from ice, and using other fuel to reproduce by budding. When it runs out of fuel it freezes. Eventually wind picks it up and blows it to the day side. Heat wakes it up and it starts turning water, CO2, and sunlight into fuel...
